# How to get a collection out of Spring config using ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, scala

I have got a simple project using spring.

In the spring config, I have a map defined as:

```
<util:map id="myMap">
    <entry key="1" value="a"/>
    <entry key="2" value="b/>
    <entry key="3"  value="c"/>
    <entry key="4" value="d"/>
    <entry key="5" value="e"/>
</util:map>
```

In my application code, I want to get this map out of spring using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext. But It seems like I cannot use getBean function as (Scala):

```
val cx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("myservice.xml")
val map: java.util.Map[String, String] = cx.getBean("myMap").asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[String, String]]
```

How can I get this Map collection defined in Spring config from a client code?

Many thanks

Regards.

Comment: "*Works on My Machine*" (tm). Also consider `getBean("myMap", classOf[java.util.Map[String, String]])` - which works as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply inject it somewhere:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="com.xx.SomeBean">
 <property name="someMap" ref="myMap"/>
</bean
```